# Unstaged changes could not be restored due to a merge conflict

Tags: git, git-commit, git-husky, lint-staged

When I execute `git commit -m "commit message"` command, lint-staged shows this error:

[image]

My configuration in package.json:

```
"husky": {
    "hooks": {
        "pre-commit": "npm run validate && lint-staged"
    }
},
"lint-staged": {
    "*.+(js|ts|tsx)": [
        "eslint"
    ],
    "**/*.+(js|json|ts|tsx)": [
        "prettier --write"
    ]
},
```

It works fine on **mac** but **windows-10** shows this error. Can anyone tell me what's going wrong with windows?

Comment: run "git status" after your hook has run

Answer (score 5):

Given the messages that are displayed : I think this hook runs

1. `git stash -k` (stash everything that's not in the index)
2. reformats the staged code, and run `git add`
3. `git stash pop`

On your Windows machine, you happen to be in a configuration where :

- a. you have some modifications which are not staged
- b. these modifications conflict with the index when you reformat the index

---

"fixing" would be :

- manually run `git stash -k`
- create your commit (the pre-commit hook should pass without error)
- run `git stash pop`
- fix the resulting conflicts

Comment: Thanks for the info. But I can confirm you there is no conflict in my repository. I have cleaned/reset my full repository, but the error doesn't go away from windows.

Comment: @Arif: updated the "fixing" paragraph in my answer

Comment: To debug your issue, you can run the actions manually : what do you get if you run `npm run validate` from your repo's root directory ? and `lint-staged` ?

Comment: As soon as I changed npm to yarn like `npm run validate && lint-staged` to `yarn validate && lint-staged` it start working.

Comment: hmmm, so it looks like a javascript issue, and probably versions of packages not exactly the same on both machines. Well, since you fixed it, I guess you won't need to dig deeper into how it works.